# There is no solution in radicals to general polynomial equations of degree five.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, quintics

I have read that there is no formula for the quintic equation.

Tow questions:

1- What does that even mean? By the fundamental theorem of algebra, any equation of degree n has n solutions in the complex numbers, so any quintic equation has 5 solutions that either can be written in radical form or not. If not, how the solutions belong to the complex numbers? are there complex numbers that can't be written in radical form?

2- How it's even possible to prove such a statement? It seems that you must try every possible combination of symbols and mathematical operations, and for each combination construct a formula, and for every constructed formula -there is an infinite number of possible formulas-, you have to prove it's false.

Can you give me an example of a quintic equation with no radical solutions?

Also, the equation $x-pi=0$ has no radical solutions, but that doesn't imply that there is no general formula for the first-degree equations!

Comment: As to 2, by finding a necessary condition that must be exhibited by a polynomial to be solvable in radicals, and then exhibiting a polynomial of degree five that doesn't have this property. You need to develop quite a bit of theory in order to do this (Galois theory, to be precise).

Comment: How about the first-degree equation: x-pi=0. But we have a general formula for first-degree equations!

Comment: How about $x-\pi=0$? That is solvable by $x=\pi$. But we are considering polynomials with *rational* coefficients, and $\pi$ is not rational.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there are two subtly different versions of the question you're asking, and you may not be aware of the difference:

1. Are there quintic polynomials which have roots which cannot be expressed using radicals?
2. Is there a *general* formula which simultaneously solves *all* quintic polynomials?

In point (1), we permit using a different formula in radicals to solve each individual quintic, or even a different formula to express each root of each quintic. We can get to the heart of the matter by dropping polynomials from the picture: it is a theorem that there *exist real numbers $r$* which cannot be expressed as formulae in radicals using rational numbers. We can prove this on set-theoretic grounds: there are only countably many formulae in radicals using rational numbers.

Below I'll address version (2) of the question, although we'll deal with version (1) on the way. I'm going to define, recursively, a certain set of "formulas". If you find it more concrete, you can identify a "formula" with a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), the nodes of which are operations and the leaves of which are the symbols $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$ and any rational number.

1. Each rational number is a formula.
2. Each symbol $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ and $a_5$ is a formula.
3. If $f$ and $g$ are formulae, then $f\cdot g$ is a formula.
4. If $f$ and $g$ are formulae, then $f+g$ is a formula.
5. If $f$ is a formula, then $\sqrt[n]f$ is a formula, for any positive integer $n$.

We can then define $F_5$ to be the intersection of all sets of formulae satisfying the above. This is the set of "solutions in radicals" for a polynomial of degree $5$. Of course the $a_i$ are to be interpreted as the coefficients of the polynomial.

Given such a formula, we can "evaluate" it for specific value of the $a_i$. But we have to be careful: notice that in general there isn't a unique value for a formula when we plug in values for the $a_i$, because $n$-th roots are multi-valued. When we nest $n$-th roots, we get a combinatorial explosion of different possible values. We can recursively define what it means for a complex number $z$ to be "a value" of a formula for given values of the $a_i$ - but not "the value".

I can now state my answer to question (1) more rigorously. If we drop axiom (2) from the above list, we get a certain more restricted set of formulae $F_5'$, formulae with no variables $a_i$ in them - only concrete rational numbers. As discussed above, we can define what it means for a complex number to be "a value" of a formula in $F_5'$. $F_5'$ is countable and each formula only has finitely many values. Therefore there must exist real numbers $r$ such that $r$ is not a value of any formula in $F_5'$. It is furthermore the case that some of these real numbers are roots to quintic polynomials in rational coefficients, but this is harder to prove.

For question (2), to say a given formula $f$ in $F_5$ is a general solution to the quintic means that for any assignment of values to the $a_i$, each root of $a_1+a_2x+a_3x^2+a_4x^3+a_5x^4+x^5$ is a value of $f$ when we plug in those values. There is no such formula $f$.

The answer to the question *how* do we prove this is basically "Galois theory". I wish I understood the proof deeply enough to be able to give you the general idea, but I don't. In any case, once we have a definition for what it means for a formula to solve the quintic, it shouldn't be surprising that something can be proved about that definition.

Comment: *I wish I understood the proof deeply enough to be able to give you the general idea, but I don't.* I gave the proof last semester and one needs some basic things about Galois extensions and some basic properties of *solvable groups*. So it is not so difficult as it seems to be. One major point is, that if $G/N$ and $N$ are solvable, so is $G$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know, but I couldn't summarize it in two paragraphs in a way that someone with no knowledge of Galois theory would get the general idea. I could certainly machine-gun them with technical terms and outline the steps, but not communicate the real intuition of the proof.

Comment: If I went to read the proof in its earliest form -without all the new theory and the axiomatic approach- i.e. as it first discovered historically, it must be intuitive and I should be able to understand it. no? does it rely on a lot of theory?

Comment: @yousefmagableh Look for "Abel-Ruffini theorem". IIRC there are some sources out there dealing with a more "grounded" proof, which on the other hand might be more accessible. (I suppose, I was thinking of [this](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~jimlb/abel.pdf)).

Comment: @yousefmagableh Unfortunately not. Mathematical history is not linear, we don't just build more theory over time, we also forget old theory. Galois and his contemporaries are going to be doing algebraic manipulations which a modern reader will find more difficult to follow because they're not as popular today. I would recommend studying the modern proof first and then reading Lagrange and Galois.

Comment: @yousef magableh: *If I went to read the proof in its earliest form ...* --- Original proofs of something are nearly always more difficult than later proofs, and even when not, often involve notation and concepts not so well known or used now. That said, I recommend: [**The Equation That Couldn't Be Solved**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0743258215) by Mario Livio, [**Abel's Proof**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0262661829) by Peter Pesic, and [**Abstract Algebra and Solution by Radicals**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486477231) by Maxfield/Maxfield (the best truly elementary text treatment I know).

Comment: @JackM: Arnold's proof of the insolvability of the quintic requires no more than basic complex analysis (his proof was in fact aimed at high school students). See e.g. this video (and other similar videos on yt): https://youtu.be/RhpVSV6iCko.

Answer (score 6):

*Can you give me an example of a quintic equation with no radical solutions?*

Try the following example. Find a formula by radicals for the solutions of 
$$
X^5-4X+2=0.
$$
The Galois group of this polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ is ismorphic to $S_5$. This group is not solvable. Hence by Galois the polynomial equation is not solvable by radicals.

Comment: I'm having a hard time accepting the claim that there is a real number which is a   solution for that formula, but we can't write it. How do we know that this real number exists if we can't write it?

Comment: We *can* write it, namely $x= - 0.116791861223 + 1.43844769533*i,
x= - 0.116791861223 - 1.43844769533*i,
x=1.24359639057,
x=0.508499484657,
x= - 1.51851215278.$ But not by radicals. Note that $i^2=-1$, so we have three real roots.

Comment: That is not approximate? it's the whole number? If yes then why we can't write it as the square root of its square?

Comment: That is only approximate. By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra we know that every polynomial of degree $5$ really has $5$ roots, so we know they exist - in theory. Like $\infty$. It exists, but you cannot write it as a real number.

Comment: The real numbers have an amazing "intermediate value" property.  There is $X$ so that $X^5-4X+2 > 0$, for example $X=2$, and there is $X$ so that $x^4-4X+2 < 0$, for example $X=1$, therefore there is $X$ between $1$ and $2$ with $X^5-4X+2 = 0$.  Math students learn about the intermediate value theorem in calculus (or maybe real analysis).

Answer (score 5):

**Are there complex numbers that can't be written in radical form?**
Of course.  In fact there are even real numbers that cannot be written in radical form (in terms of rational numbers).  Such as $\pi$ and $e$.

**There is no solution in radicals to general polynomial equations of degree five.**
A theorem of Abel, improved by Galois.  Mathematics students learn about this under the heading *Galois Theory*.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory)

**added**
Of course $x-\pi=0$ has solution $\pi$.  Indeed, any complex number $a$ is a solution of $x-a=0$.  But I intend to say: no polynomial equation with rational coefficients has $\pi$ as a solution.
A more complete statement:
Let
$$
x^5 + A x^4 + B x^3 + C x^2 + D x + E = 0
\tag1$$
be your quintic equation.  There is no finite formula for a solution of $(1)$ in terms of the coefficients $A,B,C,D,E$ using the operations: addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, radicals.

Comment: Regarding the part about (1) and the coefficients, I was about to say that somewhere we need to throw in the rational numbers, or at least the positive integers, since for example with the quadratic formula we have $B^2 - 4AC$ showing up (for the equation $Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0).$ However, this expression is equal to $B^2 - (AC + AC + AC + AC).$

Comment: Even more, $1 = \frac{A}{A}$ and from there we get rationals.